# Android EMI Calculator in Java Language: Not resulting correct as Math.pow is giving very large number

Tags: java, android, math, pow

Below is the part of a small EMI calculator code in Android using Java. Whenever i give input as P = 1000000, T = 120 (in months), R = 9.

Result comes: 9000000.0 which is not correct. I think problem is with "Math.pow(1+R,T)" as it results a very big number. I am not sure. Please help me out.

```
            double P = Double.parseDouble(str1);
            double T = Double.parseDouble(str2);
            double R = Double.parseDouble(str3);

            double Emi = P * R * Math.pow(1+R,T) / (Math.pow(1+R,T) - 1);

            f.setText("EMI: "+String.valueOf(Emi));
```

Comment: What's EMI? Can you give the formula you want to calculate? Posting just the code saying its wrong does not help if you'rr not telling us what you expect it to do.

Comment: EMI = P * R * (1 + R)^T / [ (1+R^T) - 1 ]

Comment: So did you try your formula with a calculator? Is the result different from your program's result?

Comment: R is an interest rate per month which in the equation (assuming by '9' you mean 9%) should be expressed as `.09` (That's why in the equation it is `1 + R`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with `Math.pow()`, here one thing you missed to consider. Here rate of interest is in percentage. So you need to divide `R` by `100`.

Just change the formula as below and this will work.

```
double Emi = (P * (R/100) * Math.pow(1+(R/100),T)) / (Math.pow(1+(R/100),T)-1)
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is correct, i used calculator to calculate with your formula and i get output = 9000000.

What is your expected output if u says 9000000 was wrong?

Answer (score 0):

According to the formula given here (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/279844/how-the-formula-for-emi-is-derived) your formula is missing brackets around the first part of it. It should be

EMI = [ P * R * (1 + R)^T ] / [ (1+R)^T - 1 ]